# which tinkerpop backends support upsert

Tags: tinkerpop, janusgraph

I need to create new vertices/edges without creating duplicates.
Tinkerpop since version 3.4.0 supports upsert, one can check if it enabled by backend with

```
graph.features().vertex().supportsUpsert()
```

Which tinkerpop backend supports it?

Currently I check if vertex or edge exists in python code before the insertion.